# SOLR 7.1 index field being treated as field - appearing in results

Tags: json, solr

I am converting a SOLR 4.10 db to SOLR 7.1

In 4.10, I have a field that is an expiration date, that I limit the scope of SOLR queries with, so I created an index field of type date, with a copy field, into a field in the output.

```
<field name="IDX_ExpirationDate" type="date" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
<field name="ExpirationDate" type = "date" indexed = "true" stored = "true" />
<copyField source="ExpirationDate" dest="IDX_ExpirationDate"/>
```

Using the schema above in 4.10, when I run a query, I get ExpirationDate in the results as expected.

```
 {
    ...
            "ExpirationDate":"2015-09-29T00:00:00Z",
    ...
    }
```

SOLR 7.1 got rid of the type "date" and replaced it with a type called "pdate", so I made the change in the 7.1 schema (only changed date to pdate)

```
<field name="IDX_ExpirationDate" type="pdate" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
<field name="ExpirationDate" type = "pdate" indexed = "true" stored = "true" />   
<copyField source="ExpirationDate" dest="IDX_ExpirationDate"/>
```

Now when I run SOLR 7.1 queries, i see both ExpirationDate and IDX_ExpirationDate in the results, and what's worse, its adding square braces around the date. (I'm viewing the results in json). So basically there are 2 problems. First IDX_ExpirationDate shouldnt be in the results because the "stored" attribute in the schema is false. Second, the square brackets treats the date like an array instead of a date, and fails JSON deserialization.

```
{
...
        "ExpirationDate":"2015-09-29T00:00:00Z",
        "IDX_ExpirationDate":["2015-09-29T00:00:00Z"],
...
}
```

Is there a setting that has changed since 4.10 that would cause this to appear? Or is there an extra attribute I need to set?

I have other IDX_ items but they are all type="text_general" instead of pdate - and they dont appear in the query results.

Comment: The simplest way is to determine the fields you want to get from the document. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264907/retrieving-specific-fields-in-a-solr-query

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am trying to figure out why it is appearing in the results - it shouldnt because its an index, maybe I missed a setting or attribute? or pdates may be a special case?- edited question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field type has docValues enabled, and the Schema version is set to at least 1.6, DocValues will be used as the [stored value if the stored value is not available](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/docvalues.html#retrieving-docvalues-during-search).

> For schema versions >= 1.6, the implicit default is `useDocValuesAsStored="true"`.

And since docValues are required to make Point Dates sortable, I think they're currently enabled by default:

> For single valued fields, docValues="true" must be used to enable sorting.

So to "fix" this, clear the index, set `useDocValuesAsStored="false"` for the field type and reindex. But you're getting this more or less for free, so it really shouldn't be a problem.

The `[` and `]` around your value is because the value is returned as a list, since the field is multi valued.